# writing on C# winform ReportViewer

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

I'm new to ReportViewer Control in C# winform, is there any way that I can add report viewer content without using datasets? Can I write directly on report viewer? for instance can I add labels to this control?

Comment: Use pass parameter to view report: See
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274601/passing-a-parameter-to-reportview

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value of the ReportDataSource, to different to [different sources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportdatasource.value%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), e.g. `DataTable` and `IEnumerables` are [supported sources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252094.aspx).

You can also add different labels, and map them from your data source.

Comment: I want to write on my reportviewer without using data sources, for instance I want to write my name on top of page, is it possible at all?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, check this out : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252093(v=vs.80).aspx